# Kubuntu 20.04 "Filesystem mounted at '/' is not responding"

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, kubuntu, plasma5

I am running a HP Zenbook with:

- i7 processor
- 32gb RAM
- 1TB SSD

**Plasma Version : 5.18.5**

As of last night, after performing some updates on Kubuntu my Desktop shell has become really laggy and unresponsive.

For example if I click on the Application menu, there is about a 1 minute lag after clicking it.

I have to open things in the terminal currently

An error pops up with the following

> Filesystem mounted at '/' is not responding

When I look at HTOP I see lots of red virtual memory usage by Slack, Firefox and other apps

My disk usage is ok too

```
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                         16G   76K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs                       3.2G  2.3M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root  915G  146G  723G  17% /
tmpfs                        16G   23M   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                       5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                        16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                  143M  143M     0 100% /snap/chromium/1732
/dev/loop1                  100M  100M     0 100% /snap/core/11606
/dev/loop2                  100M  100M     0 100% /snap/core/11420
/dev/loop4                   65M   65M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
/dev/loop5                   66M   66M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
/dev/loop3                   56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2074
/dev/loop6                  163M  163M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
/dev/loop8                  124M  124M     0 100% /snap/slack/43
/dev/loop7                  142M  142M     0 100% /snap/chromium/1708
/dev/loop9                  165M  165M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
/dev/loop10                 127M  127M     0 100% /snap/slack/44
/dev/loop11                  56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2128
/dev/nvme0n1p1              511M  5.3M  506M   2% /boot/efi
```

Running this command `systemd-analyze;systemd-analyze blame --no-pager`

I get this output

```
Startup finished in 5.595s (firmware) + 8.099s (loader) + 7.482s (kernel) + 6.119s (userspace) = 27.296s 
graphical.target reached after 6.112s in userspace
21.579s apt-daily-upgrade.service                            
 3.834s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                   
  980ms docker.service                                       
  808ms dev-mapper-vgkubuntu\x2droot.device                  
  760ms snapd.service                                        
  708ms systemd-logind.service                               
  491ms snap-core18-2128.mount                               
  486ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-161.mount              
  480ms snap-slack-44.mount                                  
  438ms dev-loop0.device                                     
  400ms snap-chromium-1708.mount                             
  385ms snap-slack-43.mount                                  
  362ms networkd-dispatcher.service                          
  339ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-145.mount              
  331ms dev-loop1.device                                     
  305ms snap-core18-2074.mount                               
  303ms dev-loop2.device                                     
  302ms dev-loop4.device                                     
  294ms upower.service                                       
  271ms dev-loop5.device                                     
  270ms dev-loop3.device                                     
  252ms dev-loop6.device                                     
  245ms ua-messaging.service                                 
  209ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1515.mount              
  198ms snap-chromium-1732.mount                             
  190ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1514.mount              
  167ms accounts-daemon.service                              
  157ms containerd.service                                   
  146ms dev-loop7.device                                     
  130ms udisks2.service                                      
  122ms snap-core-11420.mount                                
  120ms snap-core-11606.mount                                
  118ms dev-loop8.device                                     
   98ms systemd-journal-flush.service                        
   94ms bolt.service
```

Here is the output of `dmesg`

https://pastebin.com/PqKJX6M7